# Серверу при неправильном логине/пароле лучше вернуть 200 или 403?

Tags: веб-сервер

При неправильном логине/пароле при авторизации (асинхронный js-запрос со страницы сайта или запрос от мобильного приложения), какой ответ должен (по логике бы) возвращать сервер 200 (и в ответе "пользователь не найден") или какую-ть 403?

Comment: Если клиентская логика ожидает 200 при ошибке авторизации, придется возвращать 200.

Comment: клиентская логика как раз и спрашивает: "а как будет правильно (в общем случае)?"

Comment: 403 - ошибка доступа к странице. Не правильно в твоем случае её отдавать
Если пароль вводится не верно, это ведь не серверная ошибка. Доступ к странице авторизации у клиента ведь есть.
Нужно возвращать 200.

Answer (score 0):

Если по делать по рекомендациям [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1), то подойдет код **401 Unauthorized**:

> If the request included authentication credentials, then the 401
> response indicates that authorization has been refused for those
> credentials.

Вольный перевод:

> Если запрос включает аутентификационные данные, то ответ 401
> указывает, что они были отклонены.

[Ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11714737/5011111)